# Response.Write does not show & encode html tags correctly

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I faced a confusing issue with my new installation of Windows 10 and `IIS` that comes with it.

The issue with Classic ASP is that `Response.Write` and also `<%=varname%>` outputs html tags so that all  `<` signs and
`>`signs in the tags are replaced by the of odd character-combination, such as: `+ADw-`.

Thus, browsers do not present output html correctly.

For example,

```
Response.Write("<div>hello</div>")
```

outputs the following:

```
+ADw-div+AD4-hello+ADw-/div+AD4-
```

Can anyone say what is the cause of this issue and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I found the cause of the issue by myself -  and it was related to false codepage value in classic asp settings in IIS manager.  I had erroneously written down false value for unicode-utf-8 for which I had 65000 and which should have been 65001. Naturally, after changing the value, the issue disappeared.